# WMIC returns error when querying product

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, automated-install, wmi

I'm trying to automate the installation of an MSI on my server, however before the installation can go ahead I need to uninstall the previous version from the server.

Searching on the internet I've found that WMIC is the tool required but there seems to be a problem with the setup of WMI on the server. Running the following command gives errors:

*command prompt>wmic*

then inside the tool

*/trace:on*

*product get name*

This returns a long string of successes and one failure:

```
FAIL: IEnumWbemClassObject->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, -, -)
Line:    396 File: d:\nt\admin\wmi\wbem\tools\wmic\execengine.cpp

Node - ENTECHORELDEV
ERROR:
Code = 0x80041010
Description = The specified class is not valid.
Facility = WMI
```

I'm trying to run this on a standard install of Windows Server 2003 R2 with administrator privelages.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to automate (un)installation of MSIs, WMIC being one of them. Have you thought about a simpler approach, like a batch file that does:

```
rem Uninstall old program:
msiexec /qb /x {05EC21B8-4593-3037-A781-A6B5AFFCB19D}
rem Install new program:
msiexec /qb /i MyNewProgram.msi
```

(of course, replacing the GUID above with your program's GUID or `Uninstall` key name).

Or, you could use the [Automation interface to the Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367810(VS.85).aspx).

Or, you could use WMI via VBScript or PowerShell to accomplish the same thing as WMIC will do. But it looks like WMI might be a bit hosed.

I don't have a fix for what I'm seeing, but I do have a couple of things you can try. I recently spent a bit of time troubleshooting WMI issues, so maybe a couple of those same techniques will work here.

First, here is a VBScript that should output the same thing as `product get name`. Save it to a file `getProductNames.vbs` and execute it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService, colProducts, objProduct
Dim arrstrProducts(), i

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProducts = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Product")

i = 0
For Each objProduct in colProducts
    ReDim Preserve arrStrProducts(i)
    arrStrProducts(i) = objProduct.Name
    i = i + 1
Next

WScript.Echo Join(arrStrProducts, vbNewLine)
```

Now, if that works, then try the same thing with `wbemtest`.

1. Launch the `wbemtest` program.
2. Click `Connect...`
3. Change `root\default` to `root\cimv2`, then click `Connect`.
4. Click `Query...`
5. Enter `Select * from Win32_Product`, then click `Apply`.

This should return a list of products. If it does, then WMI is probably fine, and something is up with WMIC. If the script worked, but this did not, try the following at a Command Prompt:

```
regsvr32 wbemdisp.dll
```

then run the `wbemtest` query again.

If neither the script nor the `wbemtest` work, then probably WMI is super hosed, and you'll have to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the WMI Provider is enabled?  It is not installed by default on some versions of Windows.

Add/Remove Programs -> Add/Remove Windows Components -> Manaagement and Monitoring Tools -> WMI Windows Installer Provider.